# Pyspark random split (test/train) on distinct values in one column where all distinct values from another column are included in each split

Tags: pyspark

Lets say I have a dataframe with two columns (`id1` and `id2`). Something like:

`df = sc.parallelize([(1,10),(1,11),(1,12),(1,13),(2,10),(2,11),(3,11),(3,12),(3,13),(4,10),(4,11),(5,12),(6,12),(7,13),(8,13),(9,13),(10,13)]).toDF(["id1","id2"])`

How can I test, train split this df on `id1` (ensuring that all distinct `id1` values are in either the test or train split, not both), while also ensuring that every `id2` is represented at least once in both the test and train split, preferably stratified.

For clarity, given the `df` above, this split would prevent all three `id1` values 1,2, and 4 from all existing, for example in the `train` split, because `id2` 10 would not be represented in the `test` split.

If I use for example `train, test = df.select('id1').randomSplit([.80, .20])` I am not assured that both `train` and `test` will have all `id2` values accounted for.

If I turn it around and use `sampleBy` to make sure sure I have all `id2` values accounted for in both `train` and `test` I will end up with distinct `id1` values in both `train` and `test`.

In practice, I'm using a larger dataset. ~200K rows in my df with ~100K distinct `id1` and ~500 distinct `id2`. Thus the test, train split would result in ~80K distinct `id1` in `test`, ~20K distinct `id1` in `train` and both `test` and `train` would have at least one example of every `id2`, stratified at best.

This code will generate an example of what a larger dataset for this problem might look like, albeit quite contrived with forced skew on `id2`:

```
def rand_id(x):
    id2 = np.arange(1,501,1)
    prob = [0.10]*40+[1.0]*450+[5]*8+[20]*2
    prob /= np.sum(prob)
    np.random.choice(id2, 1, p=prob)
    return (np.random.randint(1, 100000), int(np.random.choice(id2, 1, p=prob)))
    
df = sc.parallelize([(0,0)] * 200000).map(rand_id).toDF(["id1","id2"])
```

I found a few questions surrounding this topic, but not one with the combination of constraints I have on the two columns.

Comment: In the question, you have 2 rules- 
1. same values of `id1` must be either in test or train
2. at least one of the same `id2` values must be there in train and test set. Can you specify the priority of the rules in case of collision. 
For Ex. If the df is `(1,10),(2,11),(1,10)`, how do you want it to be divided?

Comment: The example `df` I provided prevents this collision in that there is at least two different `id1` values that have each distinct `id2` value in a row. For my personal use case, I would drop all rows where a given `id2` does not have at least two different `id1` values associated with it.